# Using Objective-C lightweight generic type in Swift gives AnyHashable for type parameter

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics

I have the following implementation:

**MySet.h**:

```
@interface MySet<T> : NSObject

@property (strong, atomic, readonly) NSSet<NSDate *> * keys;

@property (strong, atomic, readonly) NSSet<T> * keys2;

@end
```

**MySet.m**:

```
@implementation MySet

@synthesize keys, keys2;

@end
```

When I try to use it from Swift code then

```
MySet<NSString>().keys
```

gives me `Set<Date>` and

```
MySet<NSString>().keys2
```

gives me `Set<AnyHashable>` instead of `Set<NSString>`.

Why and how to make it return value of right type?

**UPDATE**

Reported a [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4360).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to restrict `T` to be an `NSObject` subclass:

```
@interface MySet<T: NSObject *> : NSObject

@property (strong, atomic, readonly) NSSet<NSDate *> * keys;
@property (strong, atomic, readonly) NSSet<T> * keys2;

@end
```

Then the interface is imported to Swift as

```
open class MySet<T : NSObject> : NSObject {
    open var keys: Set<Date>! { get }
    open var keys2: Set<T>! { get }
}
```

and it works as expected:

```
let myset = MySet<NSString>().keys2
print(type(of: myset)) // Optional<Set<NSString>>
```

You can make the property non-optional by declaring it in Objective-C as

```
@property (strong, atomic, readonly, nonnull) NSSet<T> * keys2;
```

but then of course the `MySet` initializer has to create and assign
a set to `keys2`.

Comment: But what if I do not want to restrict it to be NSObject subclass? I used NSString as an example.

Comment: @mixel: Most Objective-C classes are subclasses of NSObject (probably all that you'll ever use). The restriction excludes only things like NSProxy (which does not conform to Hashable).

Comment: I mean that I want to use this Obj-C class in Swift code with my custom classes that are not subclasses of NSObject.

Comment: @mixel: I don't see how that could work. The Objective-C `NSSet` is a collection of instances of Objective-C classes (elements of type `id`)

Comment: If I change `NSSet<T> * keys2` to `MySet<T> * keys2` then it also works as expected but `@interface NSSet<__covariant ObjectType>` definition is almost the same as `@interface MySet<T>`. It seems that this is an issue with bridging.

Comment: By words "it also works correctly" I mean that it infers type parameter. I reported a bug https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4360